# How can I get both Fibonacci series and the sum of the series using array?

Tags: c

I have tried a C program which shows both the Fibonacci series and the sum of the series, taking the value of N from user. Here is the code given

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
 {
    int m[100],i,n,j;

    printf("How many numbers? Enter : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    m[0]=0;
    m[1]=1;
    
    for(i=2; i<n; i++)
    {
        m[i] = m[i-1] + m[i-2];
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",m[i]);
    }
    for(j=2; j<n; j++)
    {
        m[j] = m[j-1] + m[j-2];
    }
    printf("\nSum is %d\n\n",m[j]);
    
    return 0;
 }
```

Also, I am getting this error message :::

```
||=== Build: Debug in Array (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\MinGW\Array\main.c|23|fatal error: error writing to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccemlrUr.s: No space left on device|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Hi — could you format your code a bit please. Thanks.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: "No space left on device" suggests your disk is full.

Comment: `for(i=2; i<n; i++` is missing `)`

Comment: Added the bracket ) . Thank you.

Comment: Once the `)` was added, I had no problem running your code.  Suggest that you get into the habit of initializing variables _as they are created_. (eg: `int m[100] = {0},i = 0,n = 0,j = 0;` ).  Other than that, it is just a matter of running your code and debugging for correct behavior.

Comment: Did you get the correct sum?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the error (your disk is probably full as it is already suggested), it runs fine on my machine, but your code for the sum is not good. You can try something like this, don't need an additional loop for sum:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m[100],i,n;

    printf("How many numbers? Enter : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    m[0]= 0;
    m[1]= 1;

    int s = 1;
    for(i=2; i<n; i++)
    {
        m[i] = m[i-1] + m[i-2];
        s += m[i];
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",m[i]);
    }

    printf("\nSum is %d\n\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

PS, this code does not cover the case if n == 1 or n == 0

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I take sum=0, then this code covers the case if n==0 or n==1.

Comment: Actually it would be incorrect because your loop iterator starts from 2.

You could do something like this:

int s = 0;
if(n >= 2) s = 1;

Comment: Okay. Got it! Thanks a lot again.